# For /f processing filename with spaces

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, filenames

I want to do some processing on each line of a file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%RF_PROPERTIES%") do (          
   echo %%i
)
```

My RF_PROPERTIES points to a file path with spaces (c:\program files\Arcot systems\conf\rf.properties). It is complaining saying Environment variable C:\Program Files\Arcot not defined, even though I have provided quotes. How to get it working?

Comment: try doing  set RF_PROPERTIES="c:\program files\Arcot systems\conf\rf.properties" before the loop

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try adding the `usebackq` option:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%RF_PROPERTIES%") do (          
  echo %%i
)
```

Explanation from the output of `for /?`:

> usebackq        - specifies that the
>   new semantics are in force,
>                     where a back quoted string is executed as a
>                     command and a single quoted string is a
>                     literal string command and **allows the use of**
>                     **double quotes to quote file names** in
>                     file-set.

Comment: Thank-you. I naively assumed "usebackq" was only about the back quote handling, didn't occur to me it would affect double quote handling as well. (Yep, should have RTF-ed the whole M. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using usebackq is a good idea - but you actually have to use them :

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ( `dir "%RF_PROPERTIES%" /s /b` ) do (
  echo %%i
)
```

Comment: You don't, actually - read the bold part of the quote in my answer.