# Redirecting command output to variable in cmd script

Tags: shell, batch-file, certificate, cmd, keytool

I am writing a cmd script for creating self signed certificate using keytool. I wanted to check if the alias already present in keystore ,

So I need to execute the below command and store it in a variable. So that if the variable is null I can assume that alias doesnt exists,

```
  keytool -list -v -storepass "%KEYSTORE_PASS%" -keystore cert/seurat-keystore.jks ^| find "Alias name: 1"
```

I tried with

```
   FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('keytool -list -v -storepass "%KEYSTORE_PASS%" -keystore cert/seurat-keystore.jks ^| find "Alias name: 1"') DO SET Variable=%%A
    echo %Variable%
```

but it displays echo off. Same I achieved in shell script using the below code,

```
   if [ -n  "$(keytool -list -v -storepass "${KEYSTORE_PASS}" -keystore cert/seurat-keystore.jks | grep 'Alias name: 1')" ] ; then
   fi
```

How can I achieve the same in cmd script ? Any help will be really appreciable !!!

Comment: At first glance it looks like the quoted strings in the `for` loop, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006290/dos-batch-script-for-f-processing-filename-with-spaces)

Comment: What output exactly does `keytool` produce? Or, if you think it's too big to post, what part of it remains after parsing by `FIND`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me. You wrote "if the variable is null I can assume that alias doesnt exists". If the `echo %variable%` command show ECHO OFF, then the variable is null! I think your code is correct, but slightly change it this way:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('keytool -list -v -storepass "%KEYSTORE_PASS%" -keystore cert/seurat-keystore.jks ^| find "Alias name: 1"') DO SET Variable=%%A
if "%Variable%" == "" (
   echo The alias doesn't exists
) else (
   echo The alias is: %Variable%
)
```

Another way is:

```
if not defined Variable (
   echo The alias doesn't exists
) else (
   echo The alias is: %Variable%
)
```

Comment: If I do echo of %%A it printing the value, but if do echo of Variable it is "". Which I exactly tried the same above command. Why set Variable = %%A is not working ? any idea ?

Comment: It is your `echo %Variable%` command placed _inside_ an IF or FOR? If so, then the problem is related to Delayed Expansion. To solve it, insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning and change `echo %Variable%` by `echo !Variable!`. You should provide previous information since the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't got this `keytool` thing, I do not know what it is or does. But I replaced it with an `ECHO` command and it worked for me:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('ECHO Alias name: 1 ^| find "Alias name: 1"') DO SET Variable=%%A
echo %Variable%
```

The output was:

```
Alias name: 1
```

And when I changed the replacement command to `ECHO Alias name: 2`, the output was different:

```
ECHO is off.
```

which means the variable *wasn't* initialised, and that was expected, because the `FIND` command couldn't find the specified string in the input stream this time.

Conclusion: the output of `keytool` probably doesn't contain the searched term when you run it, and, as a result, your variable doesn't get initialised.