# For /F in Batch: escaping type filename with spaces

Tags: string, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to write a utility to take a user's comma separated values file and replace single spaces and single periods with nulls:

so (spreadsheet) fields represented as `, ,` become `,,`

and fields like `,.,` become `,,`

I'm using the type command to write the CSV to a temp file, then use string substitution on each rows before writing a new CSV with the offending values gone.  `!FQP!` is the fully qualified path, and `!INTEXTFILE!` is the file name.  If `!INTEXTFILE!` has no spaces, it works fine.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('type "!FQP!!INTEXTFILE!"') do ( some commands )
```

However, the user's files will all have spaces in them, and I've been researching and retrying this for days trying to find a way to make this work.  According to multiple pages here ([For /f processing filename with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006290/for-f-processing-filename-with-spaces) is the most succinct) and in other reference works, I believe I need to use "usebackq" after /f, and replace the single quotes with backticks.  However, if I use it in any way (with or without quotes, after /f, before or after each of the options prior to %%A, enclosed in square brackets, written out as usebackqParsingKeywords), I get errors like these:

> (when usebackq follows the /f)  usebackq was unexpected at this time
>
> (when "usebackq" follows the /f)  tokens=* delims= eol= was unexpected at this time
>
> (when "usebackq tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= " follows /f)  tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol=" was unexpected at this time

I've tried without `usebackq` as well, but I know that's where the right answer lies (that's exactly what this snippet means:  Specifies that you can use quotation marks to quote file names in FileNameSet, a back quoted string is executed as a command, and a single quoted string is a literal string command.)

I'll be grateful for any help with this!

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise on a 64bit machine, so it's not a question of my using a version of Windows that doesn't support `usebackq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is just the `FOR` loop is syntatically incorrect. Parameters for the `FOR` loop should follow the `/F` switch and be in quotes:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE "!FQP!!INTEXTFILE!"`) DO (
    REM Do some stuff...

    SET Value=%%A
    REM Replace spaces.
    SET Value=!Value:, ,=,,!

    REM Replace periods.
    SET Value=!Value:,.,=,,!

    ECHO !Value!
)
```